# Stable and Unstable manifolds of saddle points, vortex, center?

Tags: manifolds, dynamical-systems, intuition

I was reading this article on the stable and unstable manifolds of an invariant set - http://www.cnbc.cmu.edu/~bard/xppfast/lin2d.html.

It is intutitve that the stable manifold for the stable node (by seeing the figure)is the whole plane but how the unstable manifold of the stable node is the node itself?

Also how to understand the stable and unstable manifolds of the center and the vortex?

Comment: Oh I meant for stable node, let me edit! thanks for pointing out

Comment: Also the stable manifold must be a span of the eigenvectors of the negative eigenvalue right?

Comment: Yes, that's O.K.

Comment: The unstable manifold of the stable node is the node itself because the only point which tends to the node as time goes to negative infinity is just the node (the same is true for the stable vortex).